# filtrar la cantidad de caracteres que tiene un cierto decimal en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Soy nuevo usando el *SQL server*, pero necesito sacar, en un campo en donde tengo números decimales, en la cual tengo que visualizar solamente los decimales que superen los 6 caracteres después de la coma.

```
SELECT *, 
  Decimales = CASE Charindex('.', Conversion)
     WHEN 0 THEN 0 
     else 
   Len (
   Cast(
   Cast(
    Reverse(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Conversion, 128)) AS FLOAT
    ) AS BIGINT 
    )
    )
     END 
FROM CONVERSION_PRODUCTOS
```

```
Codigo_Producto     Unidad_1    Unidad_2    Conversion
    00012031               DI       BU         0,08333
    00012031               UN       BU         0,0119
    00013070               BU       BU         1
    00013070               DI       BU         1
    00013070               UN       BU         1
    0003                   BU       BU         1
    0003                   DI       BU         0,05
```

Ejemplo: quiero que se visualice solo aquellas conversiones que tengan el decimal mayor a 4 caracteres osea después de la coma por ejemplo 0,08333 este seria el único que cumpliría la condición.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio. He editado tu pregunta para que tu código luzca bien, con formato de código. Te sugiero observar qué es lo que he cambiado para aprender a hacerlo por ti mismo. Finalmente, en consultas de este tipo es buena idea incluir unos datos de ejemplo de la tabla `conversion_productos` (solo la(s) columna(s) relevantes) y el resultado que esperas obtener con esos datos de entrada al realizar tu consulta. Un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: Finalmente tenemos datos de ejemplo, lo que me queda la duda es si en ese caso ¿quieres todos los campos del registro?.

Comment: quiero solamente los registros que cumplan con la condición, de que visualize solamente aquellas conversiones que superen los 6 caracteres después dela coma. Nos se me hice entender bien.

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría lo siguiente:

1. Para obtener sólo la parte decimal, al número le resto su parte entera. Se puede utilizar la función [`FLOOR()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para obtener la parte entera.
2. Al resulado anterior lo convierto a `varchar` con la función [CONVERT()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
3. Si la longitud del texto resultado es mayor que 8, entonces contiene más de 6 decimales. La razón por la que lo comparo con 8 es porque el texto comienza por `0.` seguido de todos los decimales.

En vista de que no incluiste datos de prueba en tu pregunta, hice un ejemplo con el número `Pi` que en SQL Server se obtiene con la función [PI()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pi-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) y sabemos que tiene más de 6 decimales.

La intención de este código es comprobar de forma rápida la sintaxis y funcionamiento de mi propuesta.

```
SELECT PI() as Numero, 
       CONVERT(varchar(50), Pi() - FLOOR(Pi()), 128) as ParteDecimal 
WHERE LEN(CONVERT(varchar(50), Pi() - FLOOR(Pi()), 128)) > 8
```

### Actualización

De acuerdo al conjunto de datos publicado en la pregunta, la consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT Codigo_Producto, Unidad_1, Unidad_2, Conversion 
FROM CONVERSION_PRODUCTOS
WHERE LEN(CONVERT(varchar(20), Conversion - FLOOR(Conversion), 128)) > 6;
```

**Nota:**

No está clara la cantidad de decimales a filtrar entre 6 o 4. Tomando en cuenta el resultado esperado, la selección debería ser todos los registros que tengan más de 4 decimales. El número con el que se compara es 6 porque el resultado de la conversión queda con `0.` al principio, es decir 2 caracteres más.

Comment: hola como te va? ahora te agrego los datos, mil disculpas soy nuevo en esto. Estas son los datos del campo de conversiones 0
0,00025
0,00025
0,00026
0,00028
0,00028
0,00029
0,00029
0,00029
0,00029
0,00029
0,00033
0,00037
0,00037
0,00037
0,00037
0,00037
0,00038
0,00039
0,00039
0,0004
0,00041
0,00041
0,00041
0,00041
0,00041
0,00042
0,00043
0,00044
0,00044
0,00044
0,00044
0,00044
0,00046
0,00046
0,00046
0,00046
0,00046
0,00046
0,00046
0,00046

Comment: @LucaCaña. Para poder elaborar un ejemplo que se adapte al escenario que estás manejando, por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye: **1.-** la definición de la tabla (al menos los campos de interés) **2.-** ejemplo de 3 o 4 registros **3.-** el resultado que esperas obtener de acuerdo a la muestra del punto 2.

Comment: pablo lo edite, pero se desacomodo, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @LucaCaña, gracias por mejorar la pregunta, mi +1 por eso. Ya modifiqué mi respuesta con un ejemplo funcional basado en el conjunto de datos y la respuesta esperada. Espero sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

A manera de guía (no tengo SQL Server para probarlo); no identifico el nombre del campo que contiene el valor donde tienes los numeros decimales para efectos del presente le llamare `miDecimal`; te sugiero lo siguiente:

En un campo

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN ((miDecimal*100000) - FLOOR(miDecimal*100000))>0 THEN 
         miDecimal /* Devuelve el valor */
      ELSE 
         NULL  /* No devuelve el valor; asignamos NULL como valor */
   END miAlias
FROM
CONVERSION_PRODUCTOS
```

Como condición

```
SELECT [TUS COLUMNAS QUE DEVOLVERAS]
FROM
CONVERSION_PRODUCTOS 
WHERE
((miDecimal*100000) - FLOOR(miDecimal*100000))>0
```

lo que se hace es multiplicar el valor por **10,000.00** con ello por ejemplo tendrías para cada valor la parte `miDecimal*100000` para 1.0 seria 100000.0; 1.00051 seria 100051.0 y 3.123456 seria 312345.6 (claro entre otros) en el `WHERE ((miDecimal*100000) - FLOOR(miDecimal*100000))>0` llamenos a `(miDecimal*100000)` la **parte 1** y a `FLOOR(miDecimal*100000)` la **parte 2**; la **parte 1** será siempre mayor o igual a la **parte 2** por tanto el `WHERE` evaluaria para cada los valores antes mencionado:

Para **1.0**

`((miDecimal*100000) - FLOOR(miDecimal*100000))>0` => `((1.0*100000) - FLOOR(1.0*100000))>0` => `((100000.0) - FLOOR(100000.0))>0` => `((100000.0) - (100000.0))>0` => `(0)>0`.

Para **1.00051**

`((miDecimal*100000) - FLOOR(miDecimal*100000))>0` => `((1.00051*100000) - FLOOR(1.00051*100000))>0` => `((100051.0) - FLOOR(100051.0))>0` => `((100051.0) - (100051.0))>0` => `(0)>0`.

Para **1.00051**

`((miDecimal*100000) - FLOOR(miDecimal*100000))>0` => `((1.00051*100000) - FLOOR(1.00051*100000))>0` => `((100051.0) - FLOOR(100051.0))>0` => `((100051.0) - (100051.0))>0` => `(0)>0`.

Cabe mencionar, que lo anterior sirve para números positivos; si se puede dar que sean número negativos cambia `miDecimal` por `Abs(miDecimal)` en cada **parte** .

Answer (score 0):

Puedes valerte del siguiente *truco matemático*.

Supongamos que quieres solo aquellos números que tienen dígitos significativos más allá del 4to decimal.

Según tu ejemplo:

```
  12345   <- número de decimal
0.08333
0.01190
     ^^
     ||--- solamente si hay dígitos significativos (no ceros) a partir de esta posición
     |---- hastá acá no nos interesa
```

Para lograr esto, podemos multiplicar un número por la potencia de 10 para *correr* el punto decimal a la derecha y tomar solamente aquellos números a los que aún les ha quedado una parte decimal, por ejemplo:

```
0.08333 * 10^4 = 0.08333 * 10000 = 00833.3 <- debemos quedarnos con este, que tiene 0.3
0.01190 * 10^4 = 0.01190 * 10000 = 00119.0 <- y descartar este, que queda con 0
```

En SQL Server podemos hacer esto valiéndonos de la función `power()` que nos devuelve la potencia de un número, y de la resta del número menos el entero del mismo número para obtener la parte decimal ya que SQL Server no tiene una función que nos devuelva la parte decimal de un número.

Es decir, para obtener ese `0.3`, haríamos `833.3 - 833`.

En SQL, luciría algo así:

```
select *
  from conversion_productos
 where conversion * power(10, @num_decimales) - floor(conversion * power(10, @num_decimales)) > 0
```

Donde `@num_decimales` tiene la cantidad de decimales que te interesa discriminar. Puedes declarar la variable, para hacerlo dinámico, por ejemplo:

```
declare @num_decimales int;
set @num_decimales = 4;
```

O directamente sustituir el valor:

```
power(10, 4)
```

Con 4 decimales, la consulta a mi me devuelve:

```
Codigo_Producto Unidad_1 Unidad_2 Conversion
--------------- -------- -------- ---------------------------------------
00012031        DI       BU       0.08333

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: Si pero no es lo que ando buscando, yo quiero que me filtre aquellos decimales que tenga mas o igual de 3 caracteres después de la coma.

Comment: Eso es justamente lo que te da mi consulta.

Comment: Pero te tendría que devolver 4 decimales, y hay 0.08333 veo que tiene 5 caracteres después de la coma, o no se capas que me estoy equivocando yo.

Comment: Luca, precisamente porque en tu descripciön hay ambigüedades, te he pedido un ejemplo, para entender mejor lo que buscas, y he dado una respuesta que cumple tnato con la descripción, como con el ejemplo que has dado.

Comment: y se podría pasar por parámetro la longitud a la función haciendo ello el select más simple y también una visita que tenga una columna con la longitud y la filtraría con el where?

Comment: Claro, el cielo es el límite.